# Segfault in ArrayArray#

Tags: haskell, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement a matrix of integers as an `ArrayArray#`. It should give me a fast `swapLines` operation, that only writes a native pointer in memory, rather than copying several integers. It should have less memory indirections than `Vector (Unboxed.Vector Int)`, because all types are unlifted.

For small matrices it works fine, however it segfaults when I increase the size. Try running `crashBigMatrix`,

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash, UnboxedTuples #-}

module Matrix where

import Control.Monad.ST
import GHC.ST
import GHC.Exts
import GHC.Prim
import GHC.Magic(runRW#)

data Matrix = Matrix ArrayArray# -- lifts the array from # to *
data MutableMatrix s = MutableMatrix (MutableArrayArray# s)

generateLine :: MutableByteArray# s -> Int# -> Int# -> Int# -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> State# s -> State# s
generateLine mbar curLine curCol colCount genFunc s =
  case curCol ==# colCount of
    0# -> case genFunc (I# curLine) (I# curCol) of
      (I# x) -> generateLine mbar curLine (curCol +# 1#) colCount genFunc (writeIntArray# mbar curCol x s) -- if curCol is replaced by 0#, doesn't crash
    _ -> s

initLines :: MutableArrayArray# s -> Int# -> Int# -> Int# -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> State# s -> State# s
initLines mat curLine lineCount colCount genFunc s =
  case curLine ==# lineCount of
    1# -> s
    0# -> case newByteArray# (4# *# colCount) s of -- TODO sizeof Int ?
      (# s1, mbar #) -> case unsafeFreezeByteArray# mbar (generateLine mbar curLine 0# colCount genFunc s1) of
        (# s2, bar #) -> initLines mat (curLine +# 1#) lineCount colCount genFunc
                         (writeByteArrayArray# mat curLine bar s2) -- only writes a pointer to the ByteArray

generateMutable# :: Int# -> Int# -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> State# s -> (# State# s, MutableArrayArray# s #)
generateMutable# lineCount colCount genFunc s =
  case newArrayArray# lineCount s of
    (# s1, marrarr #) -> (# initLines marrarr 0# lineCount colCount genFunc s1 , marrarr #)

crashBigMatrix :: Int
crashBigMatrix =
  case (runRW# $ \s -> case generateMutable# 150000# 4# (\x y -> x) s of
    (# s1, marrarr #) -> (# s1, marrarr #)) of
    (# _, m #) -> (MutableMatrix m) `seq` 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems alright if you do the `TODO sizeof Int`:

```
{-# language CPP #-}

-- imports

#include "MachDeps.h"
```

And then in the code:

```
case newByteArray# (SIZEOF_HSINT# *# colCount) s of
```

You can find the contents of `MachDeps.h` [here](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/includes/MachDeps.h).

Comment: Indeed. I didn't know `Int#` was 64 bits in Haskell, thanks !

Comment: It varies depending on what build of GHC you're using.

Comment: To expand a bit more: The Haskell Report guarantees that `Int` has at least 29 bits precision. The 32-bit builds of GHC implement `Int#` as 32 bits, the 64-bit builds of GHC implement it as 64 bits. See the comments in `GHC.Prim`.